# Does the class Map has a method similar to the removeWhere method of the List class?

Tags: dart

I'm searching for a method in the `Map` class that acts similarly as the `removeWhere` method in the `List` class. I use this code now:

```
while (map.keys.any((key) => map[key] == null)) {
  map.remove(map.keys.firstWhere((key) => map[key] == null));
}
```

see: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e1a5c3c9fc475668375b

Is there a better/shorter/nicer way to do this in dart?

Answer (score 2):

This answer originally comes from jerweb from the dart slack channel, but as he is not on stackoverflow, I will put it here.

A shorter and faster way to do this is:

`map.keys.where((key) => map[key] == null).toList().forEach(map.remove);`

The `toList` in this statement may look redundant, but without `toList` you get an error, and to be honest, I don't understand this error completely. If you do, you may want to leave a comment, or improve this answer.

Here is the workin demo:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a3b98fca58162169781a

Comment: The error you get without `toList` is a "concurrent modification error". When you remove a key from the map, any currently active iteration of the map's keys becomes invalid, including the one performed by the `forEach` in `map.keys.where(...).forEach(...)` - it finds the first matching key, removes it, and promptly fails to continue looking at the keys. By doing the `toList()` call, you do the iteration up front and stores the values in an unrelated list, then you iterate the list while you modify the map, and it works without complication.